# SQL Bulk Insert Foreign Key Conflict

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, bulkinsert

I am running into an error while running an CSV SQL Bulk Insert. I am obtaining the following error messages:

```
(25000 row(s) affected)
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 13
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "fk_Employee_Store". The conflict occurred in database "SkysDoggieDaycareDB", table "dbo.Store", column 'StoreID'.
The statement has been terminated.

(1000 row(s) affected)
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 13
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "fk_Employee_Service_Emp". The conflict occurred in database "SkysDoggieDaycareDB", table "dbo.Employee", column 'EmployeeID'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

The StoreID and EmployeeID fields are created in the Store and Employee tables prior to these insert statements. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Use the Import wizard to import the csv files into temp tables. Then compare the IDs to the parent tables to see if any are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are trying to insert data into a child table before inserting into the parent table.

Answer (score 0):

When you have to bulk load a bunch of tables that are related via foreign key constraints, you have to try to ensure you insert all the parent rows first, then the child rows (that have FK constraints back to the parent).

Sometimes there is no way to get the order of inserts correct. In that case, you should drop the FK constraints until all the rows are loaded, and then restore them.